Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{A_n}X(\omega)dP(\omega)=0$
Let $X$ be a random variable and $A_n$ be a sequence of sets in $\Omega$. If $E|X|<\infty$ and $P(A_n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{A_n}X(\omega)dP(\omega)=0$$

My idea is to use the dominated convergence theorem but I am stuck on the limit of $1_{A_n}$.
Since $|X1_{A_n}|\le |X|$ with $E|X|<\infty$, then by dominated convergence theorem
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{A_n}X(\omega)dP(\omega)= \int\lim_{n\to \infty}X(\omega)1_{A_n}dP(\omega)
$$
It is enough to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} 1_{A_n}=0$ a.s.
Since $P(A_n)\to 0$, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $N>0$, for $n\ge N$, $$P(A_n)<\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$$
Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)<\infty$, by Borel-Cantelli Lemma,
$$
P(\limsup A_n)=0.
$$
I am stuck here...

I know there is a result in measure theory: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\chi_{E_n}=0 a.e.$ if and only if $m(\limsup E_n)=0$...


You cannot make $P(A_n) <\frac {\epsilon} {2^{n}}$ for $n >N$. For example, $\frac  1n \to 0$ but you cannot  make $\frac  1n <\frac  1 {n^{2}}$ for $n$ large enough.
$1_{A_n} \to 0$ in probability and you can use the version of DCT with converegnce in measure instead of convergence a.e.

Thank you! But I just saw a counterexample that $P(A_n)\to 0$ cannot imply $P(\limsup A_n)=0$. So where is my proof wrong?

You cannot prove that $1_{A_n} \to 0$ a.s. There are counter-examples. In fact, $P(A_n) \to 0$ is equivalent to $1_{A_n} \to 0$ in measure. @H.YDuan

Can we show that $P(\limsup A_n)=0$?

No, the standard example of a sequence that tends to $0$ in measure but not a.s. gives $P(\lim \sup A_n)=1$! @H.YDuan

But I am confused about which step in my proof is wrong?

Since $P(A_n)\to 0$, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $N>0$, for $n\ge N$, $$P(A_n)<\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$$
Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)<\infty$, by Borel-Cantelli Lemma,
$
P(\limsup A_n)=0.
$. Does it make sense?

@H.YDuan You cannot make $P(A_n) <\frac {\epsilon} {2^{n}}$ since that would imply $\sum P(A_n) <\infty$. RHS of the inequality cannot depend on $n$.

But I just use the definition of $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(A_n)=0$. For every $\epsilon>0$, there is $N>0$ so that for $n>N$, $P(A_n)<\epsilon$, right? Here I choose $\epsilon=2^{-n}$?

$\epsilon $ has to be  a fixed positive number. @H.YDuan

So $\epsilon=2^{-n}$ also does not work? Or $\epsilon$ can be something independent of $n$?

@H.YDuan The $\epsilon$ has to be independent of $n$. As Sangchul Lee is saying, you can find a subsequence along which you have that $\sum_{k}P(A_{n_{k}})<\infty$ . For example, first you find $n_{1}$ such that $P(A_{n})<\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n\geq n_{1}$. Now you find an $n_{2}>n_{1}$ such that $P(A_{n})<\frac{1}{2^{2}}$ for all $n\geq n_{2}$. This way, the $n_{k}$'s satisfy that $P(A_{n_{k}})<\frac{1}{2^{k}}$. And the RHS is summable in $k$. This will give you that $P(\lim\sup_{k\to\infty}A_{n_{k}})=0$. Notice that the limit is in $k$ and not $n$.

@H.YDuan In any case, if you don't want to go into subsequential arguments, then you can see my answer.

Note that $(\mathbf{1}_{A_n})$ need not converge to $0$ a.s. However, we can invoke the following general fact:

Lemma. For a sequence $(x_n) = (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and a point $x_*$ in a topological space $X$, the followings are equivalent:

$(x_n)$ converges to $x_*$.
Every subsequence $(x_n)_{n \in I}$ of $(x_n)$, $I \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, has a further subsequence $(x_n)_{n\in J}$, $J \subseteq I$, that converges to $x_*$.

Proof. $(1) \implies (2)$ is trivial. For the converse, assume $(x_n)$ does not converge to $x_*$. Then there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x_*$ such that $x_n \notin U$ for infinitely many $n$'s. Let $I$ denote the set of all such indices $n$, and consider the subsequence $(x_n)_{n \in I}$. Then no further subsequence of $(x_n)_{n \in I}$ converges to $x_*$. $\square$

Now we are ready. Let $I$ be any infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Then by tweaking OP's observation, we can find a further infinite subset $J \subseteq I$ so that
$$ \sum_{n \in J} \mathbf{P}(A_n) < \infty. $$
Then by the first Borel–Cantelli lemma, $\displaystyle \lim_{J \ni n \to \infty} \mathbf{1}_{A_n} = 0$ a.s. So by the dominated convergence theorem,
$$ \lim_{J \ni n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} X(\omega) \, \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{d}\omega) = 0. $$
So by letting $x_n = \int_{A_n} X(\omega) \, \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{d}\omega)$, we have proved:

Every subsequence of $(x_n)$ has a further subsequence that converges to $0$.

Therefore, $(x_n)$ converges to $0$.

What I wrote is wrong, right? Why can we find a further infinite subset $J$ so that $\sum_{n\in J}P(A_n)<\infty$?

Also, it seems that we show that the subsequence of $x_n$ converges to $0$ but not further subsequence. Sorry, I miss something...

@H.YDuan, In fact, for any sequence of non-negative numbers $(a_n)$ that converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, you can find a subsequence $(a_n){n\in I}$ so that $\sum{n\in I}a_n<\infty$. As a hint, try to figure out an algorithm that (recursively) finds $n_1<n_2<n_3<\ldots$ so that $a_{n_i}\leq 2^{-i}$. (Note, however, that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n$ need not converge.)

You can also solve this by using the following lemma.

Let $E(|X|)<\infty$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a
$\delta>0$ (depending on $\epsilon$ only), such that  for any measurable set $A$ such that $P(A)<\delta$ we have
$\int_{A}|X|<\epsilon$ .

So, you first fix an $\epsilon>0$. Find a delta corresponding to the Lemma above.
Now, as $P(A_{n})\to 0$, find an $N$ such that $n\geq N\implies P(A_{n})<\delta$
Hence you have for all $n\geq N$ that $$|\int_{A_{n}}X\,dP-0|\leq\int_{A_{n}}|X|\,dP<\epsilon$$.
Notice that $N$ only depends on $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ and hence only on $\epsilon$.
Well, that's basically the definition of convergence of a sequence.
Proof of Lemma: Consider $B_{n}=\{|X|\leq n\}$.
Then you have that $\int_{B_{n}}|X|\,dP\uparrow \int_{\Omega}|X|\,dP$ by Dominated Convergence Theorem.
Thus $\int_{B_{n}^{c}}|X|\,dP=\int_{\Omega}|X|\,dP-\int_{B_{n}}|X|\,dP\to 0$
Now fix and $\epsilon>0$. Let $N$ be such that $$\int_{B_{n}^{c}}|X|\,dP<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ for all $n\geq N$ and let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2N}$
Now, if $P(A)<\delta$, then
\begin{align}\int_{A}|X|\,dP&=\int_{A\cap B_{N}}|X|\,dP+\int_{A\cap B_{N}^{c}}|X|\,dP\\&\leq P(A)\cdot N + \int_{B_{N}^{c}}|X|\,dP\\&<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} =\epsilon \end{align}
